# Why Bootstrap5 dark mode is not working as expected

Tags: vuejs3, bootstrap-5, darkmode

I have a problem with applying Bootstraps dark theme. It works for navbar but for some reason it is not applied on the div which holds RouterView. The code of the component is above.

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
import { RouterView } from 'vue-router'
import { useThemeStore } from './stores/theme'

const theme = useThemeStore()
</script>
```

```html
<template>
  <nav class="navbar bg-body-secondary m-0" :data-bs-theme="theme.getTheme">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img
          src="./assets/spacex.svg"
          alt="Logo"
          width="200"
          height="24"
          class="d-inline-block align-text-top"
        />
      </a>
      <div class="form-check form-switch">
        <span :class="theme.isDark ? 'text-white' : 'text-black'">
          <svg
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
            width="16"
            height="16"
            fill="currentColor"
            class="bi bi-sun-fill"
            viewBox="0 0 16 16"
          >
            <path
              d="M8 12a4 4 0 1 0 0-8 4 4 0 0 0 0 8zM8 0a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 0zm0 13a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5v2a.5.5 0 0 1-1 0v-2A.5.5 0 0 1 8 13zm8-5a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2a.5.5 0 0 1 .5.5zM3 8a.5.5 0 0 1-.5.5h-2a.5.5 0 0 1 0-1h2A.5.5 0 0 1 3 8zm10.657-5.657a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707l-1.414 1.415a.5.5 0 1 1-.707-.708l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm-9.193 9.193a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707L3.05 13.657a.5.5 0 0 1-.707-.707l1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707 0zm9.193 2.121a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0l-1.414-1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .707zM4.464 4.465a.5.5 0 0 1-.707 0L2.343 3.05a.5.5 0 1 1 .707-.707l1.414 1.414a.5.5 0 0 1 0 .708z"
            />
          </svg>
        </span>
        <input
          class="form-check-input"
          v-model="theme.isDark"
          type="checkbox"
          role="switch"
          id="flexSwitchCheckChecked"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div class="container text-center" :data-bs-theme="theme.getTheme">
    <RouterView />
  </div>
</template>
```